# Sorting a list based on instructions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, computer-science

In short, I want to be be able to output a sorted array based on provided instructions but only at a given time. I'm looking for a Javascript implementation which works more or less like the example below.

In short, I want to be be able to output a sorted array based on provided instructions but not before based on instructions. Consider the following Javascript as an example:

```
const list = new SortedListMechanism() // our object for processing instructions

list.insert({item: 'one'})
list.insert({item: 'four', after: 'one'})
list.insert({item: 'three', before: 'four', after:'two'})
list.insert({item:'two', after: 'one'})

list.compile() 
// returns ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Now, I know this is a sorting problem but I'm not quite sure what kind of sorting problem or even what to call what I'm looking for. I'm sure an NPM package exists that supports this but I honestly don't know what to look for.

As background, this is inspired by the ActiveSupport::Callback mechanism used in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Does this need to be deterministic? If you didn't pass item 'three', would you expect 'four' first or 'two' first

Comment: It does need to deterministic. I would expect 'four' to be before 'two' since it was added first.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I haven't tried much because I'm struggling to even understand what to call what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This looks like a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). That should give you some hits on NPM.

Comment: @AuxTaco Funny -- *just today* I began reading the chapter on graph algorithms in my textbook ([Weiss, Data Structures and Algorithms in C++](http://iips.icci.edu.iq/images/exam/DataStructuresAndAlgorithmAnalysisInCpp_2014.pdf), chapter 9), and topological sorts are introduced (9.2, p.382). wwahammy it's a good resource if you're interested in implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AuxTaco had the right idea! It is a topological sort!

Since I don't care about implementing a topological sort, I simply use the one from NPM, specifically [@hapi/topo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/topo).

Here's how I use it:

```js
const Topo = require('@hapi/topo');

let list = new Topo()
let counter= 0
list.add('one', {group:'one'}) //this package requires adding the group name so we make it the same
list.add('four', {group: 'four', after: 'one', sort: counter++})
list.add('three', {group:'three', before: 'four', after:'two', sort: counter++})
list.add('two', {group: 'two', after: 'one', sort: counter++})

list.nodes
//returns ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

//example from Asthmatic's comment


list = new Topo()
counter = 0
list.add('one', {group:'one', sort: counter++}) //this package requires adding the group name so we make it the same
list.add('four', {group: 'four', after: 'one', sort: counter++})
list.add('two', {group: 'two', after: 'one', sort: counter++})

list.nodes
// returns ['one', 'four', 'two']
```

This seems to solve the issue. Thanks!